# Finding item by friendly_id instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem installed and it works great. My issue is I have comments that have polymorphic relations to several other things, like blogs. I set up the comments to be found by the id of both, for example blog id, then comment id. Like so in my comments controller:

```
  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
```

My problem is now that I have friendly ids for everything, this is no longer working. It's pulling the friendly id, of course.

```
Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=cobra-kai-here-we-go-again
```

How can I fix this so it finds the resource the comment belongs to by the friendly id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep a separation between the `id` and the `friendly_id` so the `id` is not overwritten by default and can still be used in model relationship while the `friendly_id` from the controllers only by using the Model.friendly.find('id') syntax.

[Check this change in friendly_id gem in version 5.0](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the id being overwritten. I'm just trying to locate the comment, and since it is no longer displayed by id, but by friendly id, there is the error that it cannot find the blog post with the id = "some-blog-post-here".

Comment: ha ok, sorry I didn't get your problem before. Have you tried using `resource.singularize.classify.constantize.friendly.find(id)` ?

Comment: I wish I could answer yes to that, but I'd be lying. Worked like a charm. Thank you.